# Lottie files appear with no limbs in mobile SDKs

Tags: animation, lottie, after-effects

We have a Lottie animation that was created using Adobe After Effects and Rubberhose and then exported to json format for Lottie.

On the preview option on https://lottiefiles.com/ the animation runs as expected but once that same file is used inside the mobile apps it appears with no limbs.

We have tried including hidden and guided layers as per this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web/issues/2335

- Current Lottie iOS SDK version: 3.2.3
- iOS 14.5
- iPhone 12 Pro simulator

Can anyone suggest something to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Native iOS and Android Lottie players don't support expressions.

Export by selecting on the Bodymovin panel, in the cog next to the Composition > Expression options > Convert expressions to keyframes